# ls piped into the command line

Tags: c, bash, ls

I have been trying to pipe in the results from `ls` into the command line for a C program I am writing (in Unix). I want to be able to have an index of the files and so I was planning on using argv. This is how I thought it should work:

```
./foo &(ls ~/path)
```

It doesn't work — what's the correct way to pass the output of `ls` as arguments to the command?

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is a *bit* off...

```
./foo $(ls ~/path)
```

Do note that this will choke on files with certain characters in them. Use an array instead to fix this.

```
pushd ~/path
files=(*)
popd
./foo "${files[@]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

The notation you specified does two things:

```
./foo &
```

runs the program `foo` in the background (with no arguments other than its command name).  Then:

```
(ls ~/path)
```

runs the `ls` command in a sub-shell (which, in this context, is the same as running it in the main shell).  The problem is you intended (or need) to use `$` in place of `&`.

```
./foo $(ls ~/path)
```

This runs the command `ls ~/path` and captures the output, which is split into words (using the separators listed in the `$IFS` variable).  Each word is then supplied as an argument to the command `./foo`, as you required.

We can then debate the wisdom of using the output of `ls` like that, but unless you have file names containing spaces (tabs, newlines etc,) you will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

You know how Unix tools accept glob patterns, so you can do `cat *.txt` or `rm ~/Pictures/Vacation*.jpg`, without having to pipe/expand `ls`?

That's an ability your shell gives your program for free!

Just use `./foo ~/path/*` and `argv[1]` will contain `/home/you/path/fileone`, `argv[2]` will contain `/home/you/path/filetwo`, and so forth.

These filenames may be relative or absolute, but can always be passed directly to `open`/`fopen`/`execve` or whichever function you want to use.

Using `ls` as you describe will only give you the last part of the filename with no directory, so you won't know where the files are to do anything with them (though if that's what you want, just use `basename(argv[1]))`.